# ¿Cómo accedo a variables de diferentes funciones?

Tags: c++, funciones, variables

```
/*Sólo puedo utilizar funciones de tipo void
  No puedo utilizar variables globales*/
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void suma(int num);

main(){
    int a, b;
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3;

    cout << "Ingresa numero a: ";
    cin >> a;
    suma(a);
    //num1 = resultado de la función suma <------------------------- ¿Cómo hago eso?
    cout << "Ingresa numero b: ";
    cin >> b;
    suma(b);
    //num2 = resultado de la función suma <------------------------- ¿Cómo hago eso?

    num3 = num1 + num2;
    cout << num3 << endl;

}

void suma(int num){
    int resultado = num + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Debes definir un valor de retorno, en este caso int :

```
int suma(int num){
  int resultado = num + 10;
  return resultado;    
}
```

Ya que si la defines como `void` no regresa valor alguno al llamar el método.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int suma(int num){
     int resultado = num + 10;
     return resultado;

}

int main() {  
    int a, b;
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3;

    cout << "Ingresa numero a: ";
    cin >> a;   
    num1 = suma(a); 
    cout << "Ingresa numero b: ";
    cin >> b;
    num2 = suma(b);
    num3 = num1 + num2;
    cout << num3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Son principios básicos de desarrollo, aquí tienes un tutorial donde veras esto a detalle:

**[Funciones, métodos y procedimientos en C++. Desde cero y paso a paso](https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/C++/Funciones)**

o mi página (inglés):

**http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/**

Si deseas usar tu método suma() como void, esta sería una solución:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Se define variable global para almacenar resultado de función suma().
int resultado;

void suma(int num){
      resultado = num + 10;      
}

int main() {  
    int a, b;
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3;

    cout << "Ingresa numero a: ";
    cin >> a;   
    suma(a); //Ejecuta el método para actualizar el valor de la variable resultado.
    num1 = resultado; 
    cout << "Ingresa numero b: ";
    cin >> b;
    suma(b);//Ejecuta el método para actualizar el valor de la variable resultado.
    num2 = resultado;
    num3 = num1 + num2;
    cout << num3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero el problema es que sólo puedo utilizar funciones tipo void.

Comment: Entonces define una variable global y ejecuta el método pero en realidad cambiaría el valor de la variable "resultado". Un poco raro lo que pides, imagino es una tarea?

Answer (score 1):

Haz que las funciones devuelvan el valor de las variables. Para ello:

- Define el tipo de la función
- Devuelve el valor/resultado de la función usando `return`

Por ejemplo, en el caso de suma, tendrías que definir la función así:

```
// como se devuelve un entero, el tipo ya no será void sino int
int suma(int num){
    int resultado = num + 10;
    // devuelve el valor de resultado
    return resultado;
}
```

Entonces ya podrías hacer `num1 = suma(a);`.

---

Si como indicas en los comentarios, no puedes cambiar el tipo a `int`, tendrías dos opciones:

- **Crear una variable global que se modificaría en la función `suma`**. Este método es sencillo pero *peligroso*: las variables globales pueden ser modificadas por cualquier función y eso puede hacer que buscar errores y mantener el código sea más difícil.

  ```
  int resultado;
  void suma(int num);

  ...

  void suma(int num){
      // resultado es una variable global ahora
      resultado = num + 10;
  }

  ...

  resultado = 0;
  suma(a);
  num1 = resultado;
  ```
- **Añadir un parámetro que se pasará por referencia** a la función y que luego será modificado. Así, no sólo pasarías `a` a la función de suma, sino que también pasarías `num1`, que sería modificado:

  ```
  void suma(int num, int &num1){
      // resultado es una variable global ahora
      num1 = num + 10;
  }

  ...

  int num1 = 0;
  suma(a, num1);
  // num1 aquí ya vale a + 10 en lugar de 0
  ```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero el problema es que sólo puedo utilizar funciones tipo void.

Comment: Ok. ¿Se permite cambiar la función para pasar más parámetros?